# Applicative something operator in Haskell

Tags: javascript, haskell

I've been trying to implement a Promise in Haskell based on some JavaScript videos. While I already did it like this

```
data Promise a =  PendingPromise a | ResolvedPromise a | BrokenPromise deriving( Show )

class Future p where
        later :: (b -> c) -> p (a -> b) -> p (a -> c)
        resolve :: p (a -> b) -> a -> p b 

instance Future Promise where
        later g (PendingPromise f) = PendingPromise (g . f)
        resolve (PendingPromise f) a = ResolvedPromise (f a)
```

I was wondering if there was a **class** that specified the `later` method and even better if there was an **operator** for it. I need something that would ideally do this

```
(+2) someOperator Just (+5) --> Just (+7)
```

That is take a function and a wrapper that contain a function and return a wrapper with the composition of the functions.

Comment: Is `fmap (+2) <$> Just (+5)` what you want? Note that `((->) e)` is an instance of `Functor`, so if `p` is also `Functor` then `later` would be just a special case of `fmap . fmap` (known also as `fmap fmap fmap`).

Comment: Isn't `Promise` an instance of `Monad`, too?

Answer (score 3):

There are no operators in the standard libraries that match `later` and `resolve` exactly, but `later f p` can be written as

```
(f .) <$> p
```

(where `p` is an instance of [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aFunctor)). It's also possible to use the `Functor` instance of functions to write the above as

```
fmap f <$> p
```

Also, `resolve p a` can be written as

```
p <*> pure a
```

(where `p` is an instance of [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aApplicative)).

[`<$>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v%3a-60--36--62-), [`<*>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a-60--42--62-) and [`pure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v%3apure) can be imported from the [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) module.